# Java router port setup programmatically

Tags: java, sockets, networking, firewall, router

I'm wondering if there is a way to setup connection between a client and a server over the internet and have both of them programmatic setup all needed router/firewall configuration changes to open needed external ports to communicate.

Assuming both server and client have known ip addresses and a DNS is not needed in this example to find the IP addresses. How might one have a server that when started configures access past the firewall and tells the router how to route proper communication to the server. I would assume the client may not need anything like this as it should only need to know the external IP address and port number of the server. If i'm wrong about my assumption please let me know.

Example if I have two houses house (A) has a server and house (B) has a client and both sites know what the other house external IP address is and know what port they will be using how may a Java application do all the configuration or at least do as much as possible on say windows,mac,ubuntu. The idea is the user of the server and client should not have to do a bunch of firewall/router configurations to get the application running. It would also be nice if in the example it shows how to release the connections when the server is terminated. Example when the java server is turned off it should close up port settings on the firewall and router. security and clean house.

Comment: It would depend on the router/firewall hardware being used.  If it's a linux box, it should be straightforward to do (provided you have the right permissions).  If you're using consumer hardware, that may require some more work (eg, you can telnet into netgear routers and change some settings).

Comment: assuming the user has an admin account on all 3 OS's if needed to start the application as admin and the hardware would be consumer hardware of any random router. Assuming the firewall is the OS software firewall along with any built in firewalls in the random consumer router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way of doing that as it will depend on the OS and on the many possible firewall application running on the machine. Plus, if your app crash, you will never set back the original parameters, which can be problematic when talking about security.
 Instead of trying to set up custom configuration, you should try to use standard communication template/protocol like http. This will gives you a high probability of your app running without additional configuration almost anywhere (since there is almost no point of having an internet connection if you don't allow http port).

Comment: I have seen many applications that add in port forwarding in the router when the application is installed also there must be an API for granting access past the firewall as many applications simply attempt to setup a connection then the OS tells the user the user hits the button telling the OS to grant the application access to the changes. How do other applications accomplish this?

Comment: When you said router, do you mean an actual hardware router ? Because I doubt that any app can access and change the router configuration without knowing both architecture and admin pwd (and doing that will not be safe at all). The very meaning of a firewall or a router is to control access no matter what application you are trying to run. This power is left to network admin. When you are installing a C# or C++ app on your computer, it modifies the local Windows firewall to allow whatever access it needs but it will still not be authorized in third party firewall without additional config.

Comment: When i install skype,aim,torrent, some video games. Ill find port forwarding in the router with it properly labeled for that application. This is a normal home router.

Comment: So I guess you are talking about a router provided by your ISP, not a professional one. In this case, what happen is that your computer is sending a request to the router in order to access a remote server on port xxxx. Your router will then check if it can match the port you are asking with a well known application (ex skype). If it can, it will allow the request to flow to the target server and will also open any other required port and forward data to your computer. This is called NAT, Network Adress Translator. But this will not work with an home made app since it will not be "well" known.

Comment: I see so this only works as the router companies have built it in as a fetcher for a list of applications. I guess there is not equivalent of this that will not require the router company to have you on a list?

Comment: I really suggest that you use http port (80) and protocol. It should work 99% of time even in professional environment. If you really dont want to go with that, I guess that you could use the same port as a "well" known app but you might encounter several issue with that.

Comment: I would rather not trick the router as that sounds like a bad idea. Any other options other then port 80 i feel like that would make problems if the user is hosting a web server on the same computer. any ports for general status messages or small data transactions? something to let the other know servers know that its still connected and maybe small data requests.

Comment: do you know what ports are open by default other then port 80 on a normal router. any ports that would not have any negative effects on common computer setups.